# Can a xampp phpmyadmin handle a millions of rows?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Is that a xampp phpmyadmin can handle a 4 million rows in every table ?

Answer (score 3):

I think there's no relationship with xampp or phpmyadmin, it's all depends on your database which is MySQL.
According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html) of MySQL 5.7 the size limit almost all depends on your os.

I have saw 10 million in one table, there's no problem. So, 4 million is easy.

Comment: Thank's for your response . Now I know :)